# Ошибка при построение проекта monogame под WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, monogame

```
Ошибка  1   непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "CompileXaml".
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
Имя файла: 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   в Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   в Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   в Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__1.MoveNext()

Предупреждение: регистрация привязки сборок выключена.
Чтобы включить регистрацию ошибок привязки сборок, установите значение параметра реестра [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) в 1.
Примечание. Регистрация ошибок привязки сборок может привести к некоторому снижению производительности.
Чтобы отключить эту функцию, удалите параметр реестра [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
    Game4
```

Что делать?

Comment: Пробывал переустановливать update 8.1 SDK, не помогло

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.